# net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200 AJAX ASP NET CORE

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

I'm getting this error and I'm not sure how I can figure this out.

The JS code

```js
 $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: api_url + "/Vagas/Pesquisar?idFuncao=" + idFuncao + "&idCidade=" + idCidade + "&siglaEstado=&nomeEmpresa=" + empresa + "&salarioDe=" + salarioDe + "&salarioAte=" + salarioAte + "&pagina=" + _Pesquisa_Pagina + "&ordenacao=" + order + "&isMobile=" + isMobile(),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#progress_vagas_loading").show();
            $("#pnlBtnCarregarMaisVagas").hide();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data != undefined && data != null) {
                if (data.length <= 0) {
                    if (btnCarregarMaisVagasClicked) {
                        $("#pnlBtnCarregarMaisVagas").hide();
                        $("#msg-nao-ha-mais-vagas").show();
                    }
                    _Pesquisa_ResultadoVazio = true;
                    return;
                }

                _Pesquisa_ResultadoVazio = false;
                RenderizarVaga(data);
                _Pesquisa_Pagina++;
            }
            _Pesquisa_isLoading = false;
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#progress_vagas_loading").hide();
            if (!$("#msg-nao-ha-mais-vagas").is(":visible")) {
                $("#pnlBtnCarregarMaisVagas").show();
            }
            btnCarregarMaisVagasClicked = false;
        }
    });
}
```

The result of url is https://api.teste.redtrabaje.com/v1.0/ar/Vagas/Pesquisar?idFuncao=0&idCidade=0&siglaEstado=&nomeEmpresa=&salarioDe=&salarioAte=&pagina=2&ordenacao=&isMobile=false

Image of error in web browser:

[image]

But when I try with another country like Peru works fine (only change [...]v1.0/pe/[...])

PS: When I put the url direct on the browser works fine

Please I need help with this issue, and searching on the internet I get nothing
(forgive my english, not so good)

Comment: "&siglaEstado=&nomeEmpresa=" seems like the issue in your url

Comment: Are you testing in chrome browser? Have you tried testing it in any other browser or try updating chrome to latest version.
https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/190

Comment: The action accept 'siglaEstado' and 'nomeEmpresa' empty

Comment: Chrome is updated and I've test on Firefox and Edge. I can't solve this

Answer (score 0):

I found that at the time of serialization the currency symbol was in error. It was inserted as "pt-BR" for everyone. To solve it I inserted it dynamically based on the country in which the person is logged in. Then the API returned an error because it was unable to serialize the object.